# How can I order formatted (MMM yyyy) date?

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried to change my date format from `yyyy-mm-dd` into `MMM yyyy` using  `FORMAT_DATE('%b %y', date)` function, and it worked.

Then, after that I tried to order the result in ascending order, but instead of ordered based on the time, it is ordered alphabetically. How can I order it based on the time?

Comment: How about ordering it based on yyyy-mm-dd and then *showing* it as MMM yyyy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-08-27' original_date UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-01-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-10-01'
)
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%b %y', original_date) AS modified_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY original_date
```